# Построение мульти маршрут в Яндекс Карте

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

**Всем привет!**

Снизу прикрепил картинку, и хочу спросить, есть ли какой-то вариант в яндексе построения таких маршрутов с кастомными точками(В плане свои исконки, текст). Желательно пример с реакт кодом.

Использую **pbe-react-yandex-maps** пакет

После изучения документации ничего не нашел, если кто знает, прошу поделиться, спасибо!

[image: Пример мультимаршрута]